# how to get listener to multiple documents collections

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i use **cloud firestore** in flutter and i have this structure

> **collections** > documents >  **sub-collections** > sub-documents

in my cloud

```
=> collections (users)
  => documents (user_id)
    => sub-collections (Video)
       => sub-documents (video_id)
```

i want to listen to all sub-collections in the documents (user_id) without specify the user_id

like that

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(*).collection('Video').snapshots().listen((data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to listen to a specific (named) collection across the entire database, you can perform a so-called Collection Group Query. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on these queries for an example.

In [Flutter](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore/collectionGroup.html) this would look something like:

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('Video').snapshots().listen((data)
```

This will listen to all `Video` collections, not just the ones under `users` though.